# How to fix this error on opening Form1.cs?

Tags: .net

When I start viewing Form1.cs[design] (as shown in pic) i.e form of windows application then I got this error"object reference not set to an instance of an object":

[image]

Comment: did you delete any text box or button?Because That happened to me before.All you have to do is I think view that code on the form design and add `//` to comment it out.

Comment: i haven't delete anything.coding is proper .but only in form this type of error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It means your code used an object reference variable that was set to null (i.e. it did not reference an actual object instance).

To prevent the error, objects that could be null should be tested for null before being used.

```
if (myvar != null)
{
    // Go ahead and use myvar
    myvar.property = ...
}
else
{
    // Whoops! myvar is null and cannot be used without first
    // assigning it to an instance reference
    // Attempting to use myvar here will result in NullReferenceException
}
```

Copied from other post but a nice explianation.